# Uploading to the Appstore

Tags: iphone, xcode, appstore-approval

Finally, I have completed my first application successfully, but I had two issues since last night while uploading.

1. Appnametests.octest is in redcolor.
2. right clicking on .app and 'show in finder' is redirecting to debug-iphoneos folder. which, when compressed and uploading with 'Application Loader', is giving an error 'Application failed codesign
    verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.'

When I was playing around, I went to the 'Release-iPhoneos' folder, compressed the .app file, and uploaded and suddenly the file has been uploaded.

My question is,

1. Did I do anything wrong?
2. Is there a chance that my application could get rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all relax. Appstore uploading is not that difficult. It's confusing process when you do first time. It's important you follow all the steps correctly. However, you can anytime go and re-upload the binary on iTunes Connect.

1. It's better to upload your app from Xcode. Assuming you used XCode to upload your app.
2. Before you are ready to upload the app on app store. You have to select your distribution certificate in your app settings. This " 'Application failed codesign
   verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate." **error indicates that you had not selected the distribution profile.** I'd suggest you to reconfirm this. You can check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile/CreatingandDownloadingaDistributionProvisioningProfile.html) to create distribution certificate.
3. Once this is done you have to make your app status on iTunes connect as "Ready To Upload".
4. Then you go ahead and distribute you app. Which gets submitted to app store for review.
5. When your binary is successfully uploaded your app status change to "Waiting For Review"

1.Did I do anything wrong? - If you have missed any of above step you might have made some mistake.

2.Is there a chance that my application could get rejected? - If you have made any mistakes that means your binary isn't uploaded properly. So this is irrelevant.

If you feel there's something wrong then instead of waiting for next seven days and app telling you we didn't receive your binary. Just delete the correct binary if necessary follow the steps given [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission/AboutYourFirstAppStoreSubmission.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rushi. How to delete the binary i already uploaded?

Comment: @Chandu : In iTunes connect, go into 'Manage Your Applications' then click your application. Then 'View details' and press 'Binary Details' under 'Links'. You'll see the 'Reject this binary' in the upper right corner.

Comment: @Rushi I just deleted the binary,Validated and submitted it again. Am i clean now?

Comment: @Chandu yes if you have followed all the steps successfully in above links :-) Congrats for your first app :-)